# MongoDB Query : Find where key's value from list of values

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

This may be really basic but I can't figure out how to do it.

I would like to query if key == value1 'OR' key == value2 in the collection.

Now, the list of values is long. So although

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [{
    "key": "value1"
  }, {
    "key": "value2"
  }]
});
```

will work but I would like to pass a list of values rather.

Is there any syntax in MongoDB that allows me to do so? I would be using Mongoid so if such a thing exists in Mongoid, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator which is the logical equivalent:

```js
db.collection.find({ "key": { "$in": [ "value1", "value2" ] } });
```

This is effectively an [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) in that any of the specified values for that same field will match. You should only need the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator when comparing different conditions against the same field or others. But for equality matches, this is the shorthand.

With Mongoid you can use the same syntax by diving into the Moped layer, whose accessor happens to be "collection":

```js
Class.collection.find({ "key": { "$in": [ "value1", "value2" ] } });
```

Comment: Can't use colons in Ruby...so `tom = Device.collection.find({ "device_id" => { "in" => sue } })`